# Programmatically image as UIButton but without attributes

Tags: swift, uibutton, uicollectionview, swift3

At the moment the `CollectionViewController` looks like this:

[image: cvc]

The button images are colored icons generally and I am wondering how I can keep them that way without them changing the color.

The code I currently use simply sets the image for the `UIButton`.

```
cell.iconImageButton.setImage(UIImage(named: discover.name), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Any direction to the answer would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why have a button in collection view u have didSelectItemAtIndexPath delegate method in`UICollectionView`?

Comment: Do you want to change the icon image color or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `withRenderingMode` with your `UIImage` object and set as `alwaysOriginal`.

```
cell.iconImageButton.setImage(UIImage(named: discover.name)!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: UIControlState.normal)
```